# Java getting ArrayList properties with toString

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, properties, tostring

having problem getting specific arraylist index properties with toString

- befor i use the method i create a Department and add student/teachers to..
- **the problem** is im not getting any output about **students/lecturers**

i run the method like this :

```
allDepartments.get(index).displayDepartment();
```

```
public void displayDepartment() {
        System.out.println("\ndepartment name - "+ getDepartmentName());
        for(int i=0;i<DepartmentLecturers.size();i++)
            DepartmentLecturers.get(i).toString();
        System.out.println("\n");
        for(int f=0;f<DepartmentStudents.size();f++)
            DepartmentStudents.get(f).toString();
    }
```

Student toString :

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return"student name - "+student_name+" |  student id - "+student_id;
    }
```

Lecturer toString :

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "teacher name - "+teacher_name+" |  hour salary - "+hour_salary;
    }
```

**Thanks for your time and effort !**

Comment: You forgot System.out.println before DepartmentLecturers.get(i).toString()

Comment: Calling the `toString()` method will only return the string you specified (or the default one). However you actually have to print it via `System.out.println()` to see something in your output. -> `System.out.println(DepartmentLecturers.get(i))`; Here, `toString()` is called implicitly, so you can omit that.

Comment: Thank you !
made the quick fix and its working now.

overall would like to know how is my Java syntax and efficiency (kinda new to java)

Comment: One obvious thing is that you should try to get used to [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).